# How do I read live output from executing a Python file and pass variables from PHP?

Tags: python, php

Looking at another post, I saw one of the ways to get the live output of a Python script executed in PHP was to use popen().

```
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

                    $proc = popen('python -u test.py', 'r');
                    echo '<pre>';
                    while (!feof($proc))
                        {
                            echo fread($proc, 4096);


                        }
                    echo '</pre>';
            }
```

I want to know how I can use this popen() function and also pass in variables from PHP like you can do when using the exec() function like:

```
exec("python test.py $var1")
```

When I do:

```
$test = "hi";
popen('python -u test.py $test', 'r');
```

It gets passed as $test not "hi" but I want "hi".

Comment: Have you tried doing it the same way?  By putting the variable after the filename?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work, unless it should and I did something wrong.

Comment: Please update your question to show this attempt and describe the result and how it differs from the expected result.

Comment: FYI, your `exec()` example wouldn't have worked either, for the same reason as explained in the linked duplicate.